# How to trigger click on input file element by clicking on another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I am using jQuery and Ajax on a button, to update the value of attribute "accept" on an input file upload element, then trigger click on it. But I can only do it on Firefox. On Chrome, the trigger click event doesn't work, and on IE8, it works but cannot upload the selected file. What should I do?
This is my code in handleAjaxResponseSuccess function:

```
$('#inputFile').attr('accept', '.jpg, .png');
$('#inputFile').click();
//in Firefox and IE8, it shows a file dialog that allows choosing file to upload. But in Chrome, the file dialog does not appear, and in IE8, the selected file cannot be uploaded
```

My HTML code

```
<button type="button" id="uploadBtn" onclick="getAcceptedExtension()"title="Upload" class=""></button>
<input type="file" name="" id="inputFile" multiple="multiple"style="display: none;" >
```

Comment: `On Chrome, the trigger click event doesn't work` this is by design. You cannot fake events on file inputs for security reasons in some browsers. `accept` only works in IE10 and above, and not in Edge at all. See MDN compatibility table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I can see this. Is there any solution for this case?

Comment: Not reliably, no. Even if there is, it's likely to be broken by future browser 
 updates. You need to create your UI so that the user must initiate the fie open dialog

Comment: So you mean that the user have to directly click on the input file, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: So is there any way that when user click on the input file, the value of "accept" is updated before the file dialog is active ?

Comment: Yes - that's what your code is doing. However as I already said, <IE10 and Edge *do not support* the `accept` attribute. In those cases you would need to check the MIME type of the selected file when the form submission occurs. You can do this quite easily. If you search you should find plenty of resources on how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the security reasons some browsers don't allow to trigger file input directly.
The action to open the dialog box **MUST be called by a user interaction** (a click for instance) AND the input file **MUST be visible (display != none) and focused.**

You can show to open dialog and after hide like this:

```js
getAcceptedExtension = function() {
  $('#inputFile').attr('accept', '.jpg, .png');
  $('#inputFile').show();
  $('#inputFile').focus();
  $('#inputFile').click();
  $('#inputFile').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="uploadBtn" onclick="getAcceptedExtension()"title="Upload" class="">CLICK ME</button>
<input type="file" name="" id="inputFile" multiple="multiple"style="display: none;" >
```

Comment: I tried to apply this into my code but it still doesn't work. Btw thank you.

Comment: The input type="file" does not need to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

one basic and easy way would be this:

```
$('#b1').on('click',function(){
    alert("button #1 is clicked");
    $('#b2').click();
});
$('#b2').on('click',function(){
    alert("button #2 is clicked");
});
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vf65pzhj/1/